# Error with GWT (2.3) + Google Maps API

Tags: eclipse, google-maps, gwt, compilation

I'm make a project in Eclipse Helios + GWT (2.3) + GMaps Api for this, but i've trouble in time of compile my project:

```
Compiling module com.mytestproject.MyTestProject
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/eclipse/gwt-maps-1.1.0/gwt-maps3-0.2a.jar!/com/google/gwt/maps/client/base/LatLng.java'
      [ERROR]  Internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.google.gwt.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.generate(JSWrapperGenerator.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:681)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:274)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:538)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:492)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:405)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)

[ERROR] Unexpected
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.google.gwt.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.generate(JSWrapperGenerator.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:681)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:274)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:538)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:492)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:405)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)
```

someone can help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Due too incompatible changes in GWT 2.2 you need a newer version of the gwt maps library. At this moment there a release candidate that solves this problem. You can find this version `1.1.1-rc1` at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-maps-1.1.1-rc1.zip&can=2&q= . See also the google groups announcement on this specific issue and the fix in the gwt maps library: http://groups.google.com/group/gwt-google-apis/browse_thread/thread/4087d7dfad75389e